# how to compare 2 random numbers in C

Tags: c

```
#include
int Math()
{
    int result;
    
    srand(time(NULL)); // randomize seed
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int Num1[i] = {rand()%50};
        int Num2[i] = {rand()%50};
        printf("\nQuestion %d:", i + 1);
        printf("\n%d + %d =", Num1[i], Num2[i]);
        scanf("%d", &result);
        if (result == Num1[i] + Num2[i])
        {
            printf("\nCorrect answer");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nWrong answer");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to compare between result and Num1 + Num2. But when I run code, program run with the number is too high and some line is 0 + 0. How to limit number and not exist 0 + 0 in my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code fragment is misguided. No, let's be more accurate: this code is wrong for many different reasons.

```c
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int Num1[i] = {rand()%50};
        int Num2[i] = {rand()%50};
        printf("\nQuestion %d:", i + 1);
        printf("\n%d + %d =", Num1[i], Num2[i]);
```

On each iteration, you recreate the arrays `Num1` and `Num2`.  On the first iteration, they are arrays of size 0, which standard C does not allow.  You shouldn't be able to [initialize](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p3) them either since they are VLAs (variable length arrays).  But if the initialization works, then `Num1[0]` and `Num2[0]` are set to a random value and everything else is zeroed (under the normal rules of initialization, but there's so much undefined behaviour in these few lines that anything is possible).  You then try to print values one beyond the end of each of the arrays — which uses more undefined behaviour.

Use code like this:

```c
    int Num1[10];
    int Num2[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Num1[i] = {rand()%50};
        Num2[i] = {rand()%50};
        printf("\nQuestion %d:", i + 1);
        printf("\n%d + %d =", Num1[i], Num2[i]);
```